# How to suppress Output window from appearing while publishing?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

This's been en annoyance since day one. When I publish my site using the PUBLISH file I got from my Azure site, *Output* window open and lists everything that is being done. This was nice at first and okey later but now, it's just darn irritating.

There's another window - *Web Publish Activity*, which can be closed and lists the **current** step of the publishing process. That one I like - both because it only shows what's going on **right now** and because it can be suppressed when needed.

There's a setting in VS (*Projects and Solutions > Show Output window when build starts*) to control that but for some reason it doesn't respect the state when publishing. It does work as expected when only building. However, as soon as I go <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>, the stupid *Output* window gets the focus.

I can simply press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to close it but still it annoys the rest products of the Christmas dinner out of me that it forces its way to my screen.

What can be done about it?!

Comment: it really doesn't seem like a good idea to supress output on publish, at least in the VS products I've worked with. if you did, you would get no notification that deployment failed. have you considered docing the window, so it only displays where you want it, and doesn't steal your screen?

Comment: @FrankThomas I get the notification in three ways. First of all in the status bar, then again in the *Web Publish Activity* window and also, by the web page being loaded automatically upon successful process completion. I have *Output* docked at the moment but it steals the focus automatically. It's annoying and it seems to be a bug in VS as it happens only when **publishing** and not when merely **building**. Thanks for the hint, though.